# Please Help Translate Seal Script on Old stone carving , Thank you

Tags: translation, meaning, characters

[image]
Hello, Any help to translate would be appreciated , I have a very old stone carving and I think it relates to maybe a marraige . But I would love to know the words , Thanks ahead for any help.

Comment: Similar to hanging plaques around the house with "Bless this House", "Home Sweet Home", etc, written or carved on them.

Answer (score 1):

the characters are “鎮宅之寶”, roughly means “the treasure of warding off evil influences from the dwelling”

according to feng shui, or, **superstition**; a house has an special position, that putting items in it, would guard the house from evil influences.

> relates to maybe a marraige

well, it’s not

it’s something similar to “厭勝”; imo.